# Grabbing a field from an HTML Table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, html-table

I'm building a web form that populates dynamically from a stored procedure.  It is a table with a dropdown list and a text box and one label.  I can successfully grab the data from the dropdown and the text box, but I cannot grab the data from the label.  Here is the code that populates the data section of the table.

```
        sb.Append("<td style='border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;'><select name='select_" + count + "'><option value='Pending'>Pending</option><option value='Approve'>Approve</option><option value='Deny'>Deny</option></select></td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;'><input type='text' name='comments_" + count + "' /></td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;'>" + locationNum + "</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;'>" + shipToNum + "</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;'>" + address + "</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;'>" + city + "</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;'>" + state + "</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;'>" + zip + "</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;'>" + soldToName + "</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;'>" + exemptionDescription + "</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;'><label for='select_" + count + "' name='label_" + count + "'>" + exemptionRequestDetailID + "<label></td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;'>" + reason + "</td>");
```

Here is the code that grabs the needed data from the table in the aspx page and sends it to the codebehind for manipulation.

```
function SendForm() {
        var count = 0;
        var elLength = form1.elements.length;
        for (i = 0; i < elLength; i++) {
            var type = form1.elements[i].type;
            alert(type);
            if ((type == "select-one") && (form1.elements[i].value != "Pending")) {
                count++
            }
        }
        var data = new Array(count);
        var text = new Array(count);
        var exempID = new Array(count);
        for (i = 0; i < elLength; i++) {
            var type = form1.elements[i].type;
            if ((type == "select-one") && (form1.elements[i].value != "Pending")) {
                data[i] = form1.elements[i].value;
            }
            if ((type == "text") && ((form1.elements[i-1].value == "Approve") || (form1.elements[i-1].value == "Deny"))) {
                text[i] = form1.elements[i].value;
            }
            if ((type == "label") && ((form1.elements[i-2].value == "Approve") || (form1.elements[i-2].value == "Deny"))) {
                alert(form1.elements[i].value);
            }


        }


        PageMethods.SendForm(data, text, OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
    }
```

I have alerts set up to check if it is grabbing the label values, but it is showing nothing at all for the label.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a Repeater and throw in some css classes to make things easier to find?

Comment: Regardless of how the markup is created - though I agree that's not how I'd do it - adding some CSS classes would certainly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this correctly, you're looking for the inner text (below, `locationNum`), rather than the label, of an element like this:

```
<td style='border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;'>" + locationNum + "</td>
```

If that's the case, take a look at `firstChild.nodeValue` of the `td` element.

```
var table_children = document.getElementsByTagName( 'td' );
var x = 0, len = table_children.length;
for( x = 0; x < len; x += 1 ) {
     var tag_text = table_children[ x ].firstChild.nodeValue;   
     alert( tag_text );
}
```

No jQuery required. [Interact with this code here.](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorbuley/uPxnX/)

Answer (score 1):

Give each row a unique class name. Give your table one too:

```
sb.Append("<table class='table1'...
sb.Append("<td class='dataRow row1' ......
```

Then you can find all of the elements in the table easily using jQuery:

```
$('.table1 td').each(function() {
    var myClass = $(this).class
    selectVal = $(myClass).find('select').val()
    textVal = $(myClass).find('input').val()
    labelVal = $(myClass).find('label').html() 
    ...your other logic ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `label` html tag is just that, a label. It does not have a `value` attribute like a `textarea` or `select` tag. This is why you can not get the value from it.